# Is there a mathematical representation/formalism of/for Feynman Diagrams?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

- Is there a mathematical formalism to represent or generalize [Feynman Diagram](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04182.pdf)?
- Has anyone tried to use [knot theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_theory), [Graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) or other abstract algebra tools to generalize/formalize Feynman's notions?

Comment: related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406251.pdf

Comment: Feynman diagrams are just pictures of mathematical expressions. Why do you need a mathematical formalism for a picture of a mathematical formalism?

Comment: @rschwieb: they are a lot more than "just" pictures, because they are suggestive of mathematical relationships which abstract away from the original formalism. Check out some of the papers I linked to for an explanation of how Feynman diagrams (and [Penrose diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation)) fit within a much more general mathematical framework known as "string diagrams" for monoidal categories.

Comment: @NoamZeilberger OK, if the user is looking for a framework that generalizes the use of such diagrams, then I understand. One can do that for almost anything, depending on how much one is willing to sacrifice in features preserved.

Answer (score 5):

One very versatile setting for studying Feynman diagrams is within the wider framework of "string diagrams" for *monoidal categories*. [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/) has written a lot on the subject -- you might start by reading his paper with Mike Stay:

- [Physics, Topology, Logic and Computation: A Rosetta Stone](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rosetta.pdf)

as well as his older paper with Aaron Lauda:

- [A Prehistory of n-Categorical Physics](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/history.pdf)

These papers also discuss some of the connections with knot theory.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically a Feynman diagram is just a picture that encodes a contraction of tensors.
Take a vector space $V$ and let $V^{\ast}$ be its dual. Take, e.g., a tensor 
$$
A\in V\otimes V^{\ast}\otimes V\otimes V
$$
and
$$
B\in V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V^{\ast}\ .
$$
Then you can form a tensor
$$
A\circ B\in V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V\otimes V
$$
by contracting (using the duality pairing) the 2nd component of $A$ with the 3rd component of $B$ and 3rd component of $A$ with the 5th component of $B$. Clearly, one can play this game with more than two elementary pieces. The only way to keep track of such more complicated contractions is via a picture, namely, a Feynman diagram.

In some situations one not just dealing with one picture but with a generating function involving an infinite sum over such pictures with precise combinatorial weights (or symmetry factors). The way to do this with mathematical precision is via Joyal's theory of combinatorial species. You can see how to do this on some examples that contain the germ of generality in [this article](http://www.emis.de/journals/SLC/wpapers/s49abdess.html).